# css grid dynamic number of items in two rows, prevent last row from having only one item in it

Tags: css, grid, frontend, css-grid

I want to convert old flex code to CSS Grid; How to use grid to handle a dynamic number of grid items (between 1-10) spanning two rows, specifically ensuring the second row will never have a single grid item (for design purposes)?

Previously was using JS to look at number of items generated on page load and apply a class of `fourItemsPerRow` or `fiveItemsPerRow` which added `flex` to determine how flexible each row was. I want to use CSS grid to make this more dynamic/easy to manage if there are even more than 10 items in the grid container at some point.

JSX

```
<div className={STYLES.tilesWrapper}>
 <div className={STYLES.tiles}>
  {tiles.map((tile, i) => (
   <div
    key={i}
    className={classNames(numPerRowClass, STYLES.tileContainer)}>
     {tile}
    </div>
     ))}
 </div>
</div>

const numPerRowClass = numTiles >= 5 && numTiles % 2 !== 0
        ? STYLES.fivePerRow
        : STYLES.fourPerRow;
```

CSS

```
.tiles
  padding: 40px 0 0 0
  display: flex
  align-items: flex-start
  flex-direction: row
  justify-content: center
  flex-wrap: wrap
  width: 100%
  max-width: 1200px

.fivePerRow
  width: 20%
  flex: 0 0 calc(20% - 16px)

.fourPerRow
  width: 25%
  flex: 0 0 calc(25% - 50px)
```

For CSS grid, im not sure how I would translate this. So far ive tried using the `repeat` property for grid-template-columns and grid-template-rows. Single item when the grid contains certain number of items.. Codepen here shows 5 grid items https://codepen.io/vee1234/pen/agmEWE

Comment: Not sure Grid can do this alone. You'll media queries.